# Can Sass @warn or @debug directives be viewed in CodeKit?

Tags: sass, compass, codekit

For example, in a sass file that's compiled on save using compass:

```css
@warn 'this is a warning'

@debug 'debugging info'
```

I don't see anything returned from these directives in the compile log.

I've made sure my config.rb has `sass_options = {:quiet => false}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Sass, yes, with Sass + Compass, from my experience, no.

[See this Compass GitHub issue.](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1107) My guess is that CodeKit uses `compass compile` based on what I've read on [CodeKit's Help page](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html) about how the GUI overrides config.rb and changes in config.rb are ignored. I think the best bet would be to create an issue on [CodeKit's GitHub](https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit).